# y is limit point of A, then y is limit point of intersection with precompact neighborhood.

Tags: general-topology

Let $Y$ be locally compact Hausdorff, $y\in Y$ is limit point of $A  \subseteq Y$, $U$ is precompact neighbourhood of $y$. How can I see that $y$ is also a limit point of $A\cap \overline{U}$ with $\overline{U}$ the closure of $U$ in $Y$ ?

I need to show that for all open $V$ with $y \in V$, we have
$$
(V\setminus \{y\})\cap A\cap \overline{U} \neq\emptyset.
$$

edit:
Is the following correct?
Since $U\subseteq \overline{U}$, it is $(V\setminus \{y\})\cap A\cap \overline{U} \supseteq  (V\setminus \{y\})\cap A\cap U = \left((V\cap U)\setminus \{y\}\right)\cap A \neq \emptyset $,
since $V\cap U$ is open?

edit2: corrected Matematleta's points in the comments.

Comment: It is correct but start by saying that there exists a  neighborhood $U$ of $y$ whose closure is compact , by local compactness.

Comment: The inclusion is going the wrong way and by $x$ do you mean $y$?

Comment: Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

If $\{y\}$ is open then $y$ cannot be a limit point of $A$ so we may assume that no neighborhood of $y$ is the singleton $\{y\}.$

We have $V\setminus \{y\}\cap A\neq \emptyset$ by hypothesis. Toward a contradiction, suppose $V\setminus \{y\}\cap \overline U=\emptyset.$ For each $x\in \overline U,$ there are neighborhoods $y\in V_x$ and $x\in W_x$ such that $V_x\cap W_x=\emptyset.$ Since $\overline U$ is compact, we get collections $\mathcal V=\{V_{x_1},\cdots, V_{x_n}\}$ and $\mathcal W=\{W_{x_1},\cdots, W_{x_n}\}$ with the property that $V:=\bigcap \mathcal V$ is open and contains $y,\ W:=\bigcup \mathcal W$ is open and contains $\overline U$ and $V\cap W=\emptyset.$

But then, $V$ is a neighborhood of $y$ that is disjoint from $\overline U$, hence disjoint from $U.$ This is impossible since there is a  $y\ne z\in U\cap V.$

Comment: Is it true that the Vx are contained in V and the Wx in the closure of U?